# Do all C++ STLs produce the same random numbers (for the same seed)?

Tags: c++, stl, random, numbers, generator

Do all C++ STLs produce the same random numbers (for the same seed)?
Does this hold for all platforms?
Is this specified somewhere?

Comment: Pedantic rant: `rand` and `srand` are not part of the STL ;-)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

No, the standard does not require a specific implementation. Also, the only standard way to get random numbers are `rand` and `srand`, and they are not part of what originally was the STL, but rather functions taken over from C.

Comment: What about C++11 random library? In this context, the question becomes more interesting.

Comment: @Klaim: As far as I can see, it does not mention a special implementation. It just requires a uniform distribution in 26.5.1.3 of the final draft.

Comment: @Klaim: `std::mt19937` is a specific implementation.

Comment: @Space_C0wb0y & @MSalters > Thanks, I don't know much about this algorithm so I wasn't sure if every implementation with the same seed should give the same result.

Comment: I believe that algorithm was adapted from boost random (as was much of tr1 and the C++0x std namespace additions) ... it's a mersenne twister which is faster and more uniform than your standard linear congruential.

Comment: @AJG85: That's why Python uses it ;)